my touchpad doesn't work in ubuntu24.04 on thinkbook 16+ 2024 with intel Ultra 9 185H cpu
Help, my touchpad doesn't work in my laptop thinkbook 16+ 2024 ai with intel ultra9 185H cpu. Also, my laptop will power off when lid switches. How can i handle these two problems?

Touchpad
I recently bought a ThinkBook 16+ 2024 with Intel Ultra 9 185H CPU. My touchpad also did not work at all at the first moment. After I did some searching around the Internet, I found the goodix-gt7868q-linux-driver to be currently the best working solution so far.
Steps to make use of the driver:

Git clone the repo to your local machine: git clone https://github.com/ty2/goodix-gt7868q-linux-driver.git
Change to the repo directory: cd goodix-gt7868q-linux-driver
Build the driver: make -j
Install the driver: sudo modprobe ./goodix-gt7868q.ko

After these steps, I found that my cursor is movable when I move my finger on the touchpad.
There is also another step to apply libinput quirks:

sudo make install-quirks

To make it work on boot, continue to do the following steps:

Run the author's script to install the DKMS configuration: sudo make install-dkms
Reboot the machine.
When the login screen appears, try to move your finger on the touchpad to see if the cursor moves. If yes, then you have successfully made it work on boot.

Hope this helps!

P.S. The Linux Kernel community is working on this issue, and the fix is pending for Linux 6.11 kernel: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/nycvar.YFH.7.76.2408192013450.12664@cbobk.fhfr.pm/T/
